# Told to leave in lakeview Manor

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

When i am in Lakeview manor and i try to sleep or wait i will be told i can't do that while being asked to leave.

I recently got married (Senna) and it might have something todo with it. Sadly i don't have recent save from before that.

I tried to use SETOWNERSHIP on the doors (inside and out). But to no avail.

Waiting in the basement is no problem. When i move Senna to breezehome i still couldn't wait in Lakeview.

Answer (score 3):

It's a well known glitch. It is something wrong with your mods (or their order).

Check your mods against the ones and the list to see where they should go:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ouzi9f0dma00yhd/Skyrim%20Recommended%20Mod%20Load%20Order%20-%20Master.docx?dl=0

Also, try looking for a patch on a Nexus!

Comment: I have tried looking for fixes al lot, i also have used LOOT for loadorder, but i will look at that list of yours when i get the chance. haven't seen it yet so it might do the trick.